# formatters for List[DateTime] play scala

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I am working on a project using Play, Scala, MongoDB. I want to store the `List[Datetime]` in a collection, so I need fomatters for it. To store the `Datetime` I used this formatter

```
implicit def dateFormat = {
  val dateStandardFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

  val dateReads: Reads[DateTime] = Reads[DateTime](js =>
    js.validate[JsObject].map(_.value.toSeq).flatMap {
      case Seq(("$date", JsNumber(ts))) if ts.isValidLong =>
        JsSuccess(new DateTime(ts.toLong))
      case _ =>
        JsError(__, "validation.error.expected.$date")
    }
  )

  val dateWrites: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
    def writes(dateTime: DateTime): JsValue = Json.obj("$date"-> dateTime.getMillis())
  }

  Format(dateReads, dateWrites)
}
```

but for storing list of datetimes it is not  working. thanks in advance for help

Comment: Could you please provide the output / stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: i defined model like this     case class test(dates: List[Datetime], ....)                       using the above formatter,   implicit val dateModelFormat :OFormat[test] = (
    (JsPath \ "_id").format[String] and (JsPath \ "time").format[List[DateTime]]  but it is not wrking in db it is saving number Long instead of datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an implicit json Writer and Reader for the List[DateTime]. In your example, you are only defining how to serialize and deserialize the DateTime type. Adding this below the formatter should make the framework know how to *JSONify* DateTime lists.
See working example below:

```
  val dateStandardFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

  val dateReads: Reads[DateTime] = Reads[DateTime](js =>
    js.validate[JsObject].map(_.value.toSeq).flatMap {
      case Seq(("$date", JsNumber(ts))) if ts.isValidLong =>
        JsSuccess(new DateTime(ts.toLong))
      case _ =>
        JsError(__, "validation.error.expected.$date")
    }
  )

  val dateWrites: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
    def writes(dateTime: DateTime): JsValue = Json.obj("$date" -> dateTime.getMillis())
  }

  implicit def dateFormat = Format(dateReads, dateWrites)

  implicit val listDateTimeFormat = Format(Reads.list[DateTime](dateReads), Writes.list[DateTime](dateWrites))

  val m = List(DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now())

  println(Json.toJson(m).toString())
```

Comment: when i tried to use    implicit val listDateTimeFormat = Format(Json.reads[List[DateTime]], Json.writes[List[DateTime]]    it is throwing an error that  No unapply or unapplySeq function found
[error]     implicit val writes = Json.writes[List[DateTime]]

Comment: Hi Kittu, I updated the example as I made a small mistake on my initial response

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MongoDateFormats` from this project [simple-reactivemongo](https://github.com/hmrc/simple-reactivemongo/blob/master/src/main/scala/uk/gov/hmrc/mongo/json/ReactiveMongoFormats.scala)